# Google Map not loading in php

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using google map in my project and it was working well before, I entered Javascript to put some marker using Googles demo ([Using MySQL and PHP with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps)).  After adding following java script google map was not loading can anyone help me.

```js
<script>
      var customLabel = {
        restaurant: {
          label: 'R'
        },
        bar: {
          label: 'B'
        }
      };

        function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.115878, 74.188597),
          zoom: 12
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
  var id = location.search.split('order_id=')[1];
  var link="http://localhost/load/companyPages/orderDetails.php?order_id="+id;
          // Change this depending on the name of your PHP or XML file
          downloadUrl(link, function(data) {
            var xml = data.responseXML;
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
           function( markers[0]) {
              var address = markers[0].getAttribute('pickUpAddress');
              
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[0].getAttribute('picklat')),
                  parseFloat(markers[0].getAttribute('picklng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              

            
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            };
    function( markers[1]) {
              var address = markers[1].getAttribute('droppingAddress');
              
              var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
                  parseFloat(markers[1].getAttribute('drplat')),
                  parseFloat(markers[1].getAttribute('drplng')));

              var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
              var strong = document.createElement('strong');
              strong.textContent = address
              infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
              

            
              var icon = customLabel[type] || {};
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: point,
                label: icon.label
              });
              marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              });
            };
          });
        }



      function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
        var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
            new XMLHttpRequest;

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
          }
        };

        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.send(null);
      }

      function doNothing() {}
    </script>
```

I have following XML file that links returns

How can, I solve this so,I could carry on with remaining stuff in my project.

**XML:**

```
<markers>
 <marker pickUpAddress="Kamoki,null,Kamoki,Gujranwala,Punjab,Pakistan " picklat="74.21228405088186" picklng="31.97541484428519"/>
 <marker droppingAddress="Grand Trunk Road,null,Gujranwala,null,null,Pakistan" drplat="74.19072143733501" drplng="32.15837860897405"/>
</markers>
```

Comment: Here is the XML.

Comment: <markers>
<marker pickUpAddress="Kamoki,null,Kamoki,Gujranwala,Punjab,Pakistan " picklat="74.21228405088186" picklng="31.97541484428519"/>
<marker droppingAddress="Grand Trunk Road,null,Gujranwala,null,null,Pakistan" drplat="74.19072143733501" drplng="32.15837860897405"/>
</markers>

Comment: You are correct, Google maps does not load in php. I don't understand why you have tagged php or or even mention php in question.

Comment: where is the html (or the php with html) code  ?.. if you don't have a proper html head  for load the google maps  refer ... the js  can't work

Comment: Map was loading before I modified these JS lines which are reading XML data

Comment: here is the error from console 
"initMap is not a function", name: "InvalidValueError", stack: "Error↵ at new gc

Comment: Please, please, please... don't post required information for your question in the comments [edit] your question to add the required information (like the XML and the error message, etc).

Comment: Added the XML to the question.  Your addresses look strange, but that may not be relevant...

Comment: I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`, on this line: `function(markers[0]) {`.  I have no idea what you are trying to do there.